# RabbitMQ and Celery: subscribe to job done event

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have a simple Celery **`task.py`** running with **RabbitMQ** message broker and **Redis** data storage

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend="redis://localhost:6379/0")

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

and a **`listener.py`** service, with a trivial function

```
def on_add(result):
    # Do something with the result.
```

I want to invoke `add()` with a fire-and-forget style, and let another service implementing `on_add()` handle results.

This is the diagram of the workflow:

[image]

How can I create a listener that subscribes to task completion events on Celery's backend, Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options here:

1. Use signals - [task-postrun](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#task-postrun) for instance:

```
@task_postrun.connect
def task_postrun_handler(task_id, task, args, retval, **kwargs):
    if task.name == "add":
        on_add(retval)
```

note that it will run in the same celery worker.

2. If you need it in a separate process, you can take flower's approach and [listen to the broker's events](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/flower/events.py#L191) (more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "link" to run task after your task finishes:

```py
add.s().apply_async(
   link=notify.s()
)
```

This will run `add` task and after it finishes it will run `notify` with result of add.

PS: there is also link_error, that run tasks if your task fails